# Am I violating the Law of Demeter here?

Tags: java, jsp, el

This violates the `Law of Demeter` right? See `${book.author.name}` and `${book.category.name}` below. Is it ok to do this in a JSP with Expression Language?

```
<c:set var="book" value="${book}" />

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Title:</td><td><c:out value="${book.title}" /></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${book.description}" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price: </td><td><c:out value="${book.price}" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Author: </td><td><c:out value="${book.author.name}" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Category: </td><td><c:out value="${book.category.name}" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

`${book}` attribute is a `Book` object. `BookServlet`:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");

BookService bookService = new BookService();
Book book = bookService.getBookById(Integer.valueOf(id));

request.setAttribute("book", book);
```

`findBookById()` from `BookService -> BookDao`

```
public Book findBookById(int id) throws DaoException {

Book book = null;
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    con = this.getConnection();

    ps = con.prepareStatement(FIND_BOOK_BY_ID);
    ps.setInt(1, id);

    //Using a PreparedStatement to execute SQL...
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        int bookId = rs.getInt("book_id");
        String title = rs.getString("title");
        String desc = rs.getString("description");
        int authorId = rs.getInt("author_id");
        String authorName = rs.getString("author_name");
        int categoryId = rs.getInt("category_id");
        String categoryName = rs.getString("book_category_name");
        double price = rs.getDouble("price");

        book = new Book(bookId);
        book.setTitle(title);
        book.setDescription(desc);
        book.setPrice(price);

        Author author = new Author(authorId);
        author.setName(authorName);
        book.setAuthor(author);

        Category category = new Category(categoryId);
        category.setName(categoryName);                
        book.setCategory(category);
}
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new DaoException("findBookById() " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    try {
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            ps.close();
        }
        if (con != null) {
            freeConnection(con);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DaoException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
return book;
```

}

Comment: Maybe this would be better on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I just read `Misunderstanding the Law of Demeter` @ http://www.dan-manges.com/blog/37. He says it's fine to do in `views`?

Comment: Here's another take on it - [The Law of Demeter Is Not A Dot Counting Exercise](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx) by Phil Haack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a strict sense, you're violating the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter): You're invoking methods on objects returned by Book methods, exposing internal structure of Author and Category classes.

On the other side, I don't see that you're code is harmful and you're infraction of Demeter Law seems naive. I've seen JSP files like yours many times in books and production code and there was no harm at all.

But, if you still want to follow the Law, you can use something similar to a [Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) that has only the attributes that you're JSP needs to display.There's an extra work needed to populate DTO instances with the information of Book, Author and Category classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly valid use of a jsp. It would take more work to do this an other way than it's worth. Strict adherence to coding principles that were developed when COBOL was still popular is only interesting in academia.